# A projection which has $||E\alpha|| \le ||\alpha||$ is an orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra

this problem screwed me up for a long time. Please help me solve this.

> > $V$ is an inner product space and $W$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $V$. Prove that if $E$ is a projection with range $W$, then $E$ is the orthogonal projection on $W$ iff $||E\alpha|| \le ||\alpha||$ for all $\alpha$ in $V$.

I can prove that if $E$ is an orthogonal projection then $||E\alpha|| \le ||\alpha||$ using property: $(E\alpha | \beta) = (\alpha|\beta)$ for all $\alpha$ in $V$ and $\beta$ in W. But the converse seems more difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $V = W \oplus \ker(E)$. If $E$ is not orthogonal, then there is $b\in ker(E)$ and $a\in W$ such that $(a|b)\neq 0$. Let us consider $\alpha=\lambda a+b$.

$$\|\alpha\|^2= \|\lambda a\|^2+2\lambda\operatorname{Re}(a|b)+\|b\|^2 = \|E\alpha\|^2+2\lambda\operatorname{Re}(a|b)+\|b\|^2$$

using $\lambda = -\dfrac{\|b\|^2}{\operatorname{Re}(a|b)}$ yields $\|\alpha\|^2 =  \|E\alpha\|^2-\|b\|^2 < \|E\alpha\|^2$

so if it's not orthogonal, the relation is not verified. If it is verified, the projection must be orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's a simple and brief solution for such a problem

Comment: You can use the same method for the converse : If $E$ is orthogonal, and $\alpha=a+b$ then $\|\alpha\|^2= \|\ a\|^2+\|b\|^2 = \|E\alpha\|^2+\|b\|^2 \geq \|E\alpha\|^2$

Comment: It's more simple than my method. so great ^^.thanks

Comment: Why $(a|b)=(b|a)$ in your solution?

Comment: @Majid It's not (unless it is a real number). But they are conjugates, so the imaginary parts cancel out and you're left with twice the real part (Re) (sry I'm late)